# How to test that a method gets called in a do-end block in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method that I am writing a test for. I want to test that `generate_csv_header` and `generate_csv_line` gets called.

```
def generate_temporary_report_file(temporary_file)
  CSV.open(temporary_file, "wb") do |csv|
    csv << generate_csv_header
    csv << generate_csv_line
  end
  temporary_file
end
```

Here is my test so far:

```
describe '#generate_temporary_report_file' do
  let(:temp_file) { double(:temp_file, read: 'content') }
  let(:csv_open)  { double(:csv_open) }

  before do
    expect(CSV).to receive(:open).with(temp_file, "wb").and_return(csv_open)
    # expect(item_report_generator).to receive(:generate_csv_header).once
    # expect(item_report_generator).to receive(:generate_csv_line).once
  end

  it 'returns temporary file' do
    expect(item_report_generator.generate_temporary_report_file(temp_file)).to eq temp_file
  end
end
```

I commented out two lines because those methods are getting stubbed out.

**How do I test that `generate_csv_header` and `generate_csv_line` gets called once?**

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem if you uncomment those lines? Even if you're stubbing the methods, the expectation of them being called should still work.

Comment: @Humza The test says that it is expecting it one time, but is receiving it 0 times.

Comment: Try the following `expect(item_report_generator.class.any_instance).to receive(:method_name).once` or `expect_any_instance_of(item_report_generator.class).to receive(:method_name).once`

Comment: `any_instance` doesn't exist, besides, that specific instance should receive it

Comment: You've ensured that the methods are called, right? If not, a good idea would be to `raise 'random error'` in `generate_csv_header` and see if you encounter it during the test.

Comment: The methods are definitely getting called in production/development, but not in the test. The issue is that I have `expect(CSV).to receive(:open).with(temp_file, "wb").and_return(csv_open)` which is stubbing the method. My question is how do I test that `csv_open` will receive a block which would then execute `generate_csv_header` and `generate_csv_line`?

Comment: I think you better update your post and share exactly what it is that you're stubbing. I now understand that the code in your block is never getting called because of how you're stubbing the methods. And I don't think you can run a proper test this way. I shall try to respond with a proper solution after you've updated your post.

Comment: That's why I posted this question. I am stuck here.